# sinatra + sinatra-authentication + mongoid: which versions?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I'm prototyping a REST service with sinatra + mongoid. While looking for an authentication module, it looked like that sinatra-authentication was doing what I require from it. My problem is that I can't make all those stuffs work together. I'm probably using the wrong set of versions together.

I'm using:

- ruby 1.9.3 (required for mongoid 3)
- mongoid 3.0.13
- sinatra 1.3.3
- sinatra-authentication 0.4.2 from git master (as 0.4.1 does not work with mongoid > 3 and 0.4.2 is not available as gem)
- mongo 1.7.1

mongoid is correctly configured as I can query mongo and get results, but when I plug sinatra-authentication in, I get errors.

Does anyone knows which versions are recent enough and happens to work together ?

Comment: Are you using Bundler to help with the dependency management? Can you post some of the errors you're getting?

Comment: yes, I'm using bundle. I manage to 'signup' users (even if I got a error message, the user is added to the db) but it fails on login with  "undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass". The stacktrace is there https://gist.github.com/4150697

Comment: @jboursiquot if you have those pieces working together, would you mind sharing the version numbers? At this point, I'm more interested by having something that work instead of trying to fix my problem with the versions I use.